# sql query -join to get the following result

Tags: asp.net, sql

i am having 2 table, from this 2 table result, i need to get the 3rd table,my 1st table query result as follow

```
select categeoryid,EmployeeId,SUM(Amount)as advance
from ExpenditureDetails where Expenditurefor='Travel' and EmployeeId='TFIPL201145' 
group by categeoryid,EmployeeId 

categeoryid            EmployeeId           advance
----------------------------------------------------
Local_IPL              TFIPL201145          1000
Project_Audio release  TFIPL201145          566565
Project_Cricketscore   TFIPL201145          441898
Project_mayajal        TFIPL201145          1100
Project_Tennis         TFIPL201145          8949
```

2nd table result as follow

```
select categeoryid,EmployeeId,SUM(Amount)as submitted_amt
from ExpenditureTravelling where EmployeeId='TFIPL201145'  
group by categeoryid,EmployeeId

categeoryid          EmployeeId     submitted_amt
-------------------------------------------------
Event_Golf           TFIPL201145    36456
Events_Hokey         TFIPL201145    1303
local                TFIPL201145    25000
Local_IPL            TFIPL201145    1169488
Project              TFIPL201145    16000
Project_Cricketscore TFIPL201145    216661
Project_harris       TFIPL201145    53453
Project_mayajal      TFIPL201145    1500
Project_Tennis       TFIPL201145    8949
```

i want my result table should be...joining 2 table

```
categeoryid               EmployeeId        advance      submitted_amt
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Event_Golf                TFIPL201145       0            36456
Events_Hokey              TFIPL201145       0            1303
local                     TFIPL201145       0            25000
Local_IPL                 TFIPL201145       1000         1169488
Project                   TFIPL201145       0            16000
Project_Cricketscore      TFIPL201145       441898       216661
Project_harris            TFIPL201145       0            53453
Project_mayajal           TFIPL201145       1100         1500
Project_Tennis            TFIPL201145       8949         8949
```

can u plz help for this query...to get the result...

Comment: Could you please try to format the question to be a bit more readable? Right now it'll be much more work figuring the question out than constructing the SQL.

Comment: hi,joachim Isaksson,now u can read my query?

Answer (score 0):

You have to join both queries using a relative link between them. From what I can tell, EmployeeId is a good candidate. Something like:

```
select categoryId, EmployeeId, SUM(Amount) as advance, Travelling.submitted_amt
from ExpenditureDetails inner join
 (select CategoryId, EmployeeId, sum(Amount) as submitted_amt
  from ExpenditureTravelling) as Travelling on
 ExpenditureDetails.EmployeeId = Travelling.EmployeeId
where
  (EmployeeId='TFIPL201145') group by....
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

select a.categoryId,a.EmployeeId,isnull(sum(a.Amount),0) as submitted_amt,
isnull((select sum(b.amount) from ExpenditureDetails b where b.categoryId = a.categoryId and b.Expenditurefor='Travel' group by b.categeoryid,b.EmployeeId)),0) as advance
from ExpenditureDetails a 
where a.EmployeeId='TFIPL201145'
group by a.categeoryid,a.EmployeeId